Blazor default scaffolded CRUD create page not finding model
I created several CRUD pages based on my models, using the create scafolded item as per the Blazor tutorial. For some reason I can't figure out, some of them are working and some of them don't.
The code here is nearly identical to a similar create page I have for another model. The SQL database has the table. Even the Edit form works perfectly, after I added an entry to the SQL database via query. But the Create page throws this error:

InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.

I tried explicitly creating an instance of the model in the initialize function, but the binding would not work. I am completely at a loss.
@page "/characters/create"
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@using App.src.Models
@inject IDbContextFactory<SciFiLarpApp.Data.AppContext> DbFactory
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<PageTitle>Create</PageTitle>

<h1>Create</h1>

<h2>Ship</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <EditForm method="post" Model="Ship" OnValidSubmit="AddShip" FormName="create" Enhance>
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" />
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label> 
                <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="Ship.Name" class="form-control" /> 
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Ship.Name" class="text-danger" /> 
            </div>        
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="captainid" class="form-label">CaptainID:</label> 
                <InputNumber id="captainid" @bind-Value="Ship.CaptainID" class="form-control" /> 
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Ship.CaptainID" class="text-danger" /> 
            </div>        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="/ships">Back to List</a>
</div>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private Ship Ship { get; set; } = new();

    private async Task AddShip()
    {
        using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        context.Ship.Add(Ship);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/ships");
    }
}

And here's my model:
namespace App.src.Models
{
    public class Ship
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int CaptainID { get; set; }
        public Character Captain { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}


Could you please tell me which tutorial you have followed? I tested your codes and it works well.

Is this an interactive or statically rendered page?  How is the application configured  Server/WASM/Auto?  Global or PerPage/Component Interactivity?

I was basing my work off of this playlist from .net youtube channel. The SQL portion is in video 9. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHDox4Fx6G0&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oXNZX1Q8rB-5xgTSKR8qA5k

I would avoid the name / namespace collisions like "App" this can cause havoc with the source code generators it shouldn't but it does sometimes.
